# How to add a blue selection rectangle to ListView?

Tags: c, winapi

Does a Windows API ListView supports this selection rectangle?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I stand corrected. If the `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` is added to the extended list view style, then the control performs alpha blended marquee selection. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732.aspx) says:

> **LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER**
>
> Version 6.00 and later. Paints via double-buffering, which reduces
>   flicker. This extended style also enables alpha-blended marquee
>   selection on systems where it is supported.

Thanks to @andlabs for pointing this out.

---

> Does a Windows API ListView supports this selection rectangle?

No. The image in the question comes from the private list view control, DirectUIHWND. This control is used in a variety of Microsoft software and is especially visible in Explorer. Third party programs don't have access to this control.

If you want functionality like this you will have to implement it yourself. The system list view control, SysListView32, has no such functionality.

Comment: But isn't that the `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` marquee selection look?

Comment: @andlabs Hmm. Interesting. I suspect the image in the Q comes from explorer, but blended marquee selection may well look the same. If you know better please do answer and I will defer to your superior expertise.

Comment: @andlabs I tried adding that style to a list view and did not see any marquee selection. Do you know more?

Comment: @David Heffernan I have tried it and it worked: `SendMessage(hListView, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);` (note that it only worked when I enabled visual styles).

Comment: Thanks. I was applying the extended style incorrectly. I agree with you.