# Decide: How to draw FrameRect on top of the ListView

Tags: listview, winapi

I need draw *FrameRect* on top of the **ListView**. If I draw this in main loop:

```
loop GetMessage(...) do
...
FrameRect();
...
TranslateMessage(...);
DispatchMessage(...);
```

It is don't work, because, the Frame is drawn only occurs when some action. Otherwise, it will be erased.

Next, I try draw *FrameRect* in **NM_CUSTOMDRAW** (in case: **CDDS_SUBITEM** || **CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT**):

```
...

//
FrameRect(...);
//
return CDRF_NEWFONT;
...
```

And this not working fully...

How to correctly draw *FrameRect* on top of the **ListView**?

[image: FrameRect]

This animation uses the first method. If the mouse is not moved, and the cycle is not receiving other events, nothing will be drawn.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you are looking for.

Comment: @andlabs I add gif image.

Comment: Is this for selecting items?

Comment: Yes, I changed the default event handler TreeView.

Comment: Oh, so you are trying to add marquee selection to a tree view? Not to a list view? Those are two separate controls. Anyway what you are doing will not work. You will need to supplant the window procedure, either by handling `WM_NOTIFY` messages or by subclassing. and keeping the message pump the same. I forget if marquee selection starts a modal message loop or not; even if it does, you can't just draw in your message loop.

Comment: Yes, I use subclassing for this. Now, I needed draw frame for selecting items. WM_PAINT for ListView did not received...

Comment: How release FrameDraw in WM_NOTIFY?

Comment: You need to keep track of whether you are in a marquee selection and the current marquee rect. This can't be done statelessly.

Comment: In fact, needed an analogue processing of the message WM_PAINT for ListView. But, WM_PAINT for ListView did not received.

Comment: You want `InvalidateRect()`.

Comment: InvalidateRect gives glare

Comment: You can check InvertRect instead. Here is a sample source code: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~stotts/145/homes/bball/online_code/GridCtrl.cpp

Comment: List view already supports marquee selection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231259/how-to-add-a-blue-selection-rectangle-to-listview

Comment: Thank you, all... I have decided this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be decided by as follows:

Add in WndProc code for **WM_NOTIFY** with **NM_CUSTOMDRAW**.

```
case CDDS_SUBITEM || CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT
...
return CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT

...
case CDDS_SUBITEM || CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT
//
if (!ListViewMouseRelease)
{
//
hbr.lbColor=0;
//
hbr.lbStyle=BS_SOLID;
//
hbr.lbHatch=0;

//
SelectObject(LPNMLVCD.nmcd.hdc, ExtCreatePen(PS_GEOMETRIC || PS_DOT, 1, hbr, 0, 0));

//
MoveToEx(LPNMLVCD.nmcd.hdc, ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Left+1,  ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Top-1, 0);

//
LineTo(LPNMLVCD.nmcd.hdc, ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Right-1,  ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Top-1);

//
LineTo(LPNMLVCD.nmcd.hdc, ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Right-1,  ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Bottom);

//
MoveToEx(LPNMLVCD.nmcd.hdc, ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Right-2,  ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Bottom, 0);

//
LineTo(LPNMLVCD.nmcd.hdc, ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Left,  ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Bottom);

//
LineTo(LPNMLVCD.nmcd.hdc, ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Left, ListViewMouseOldAreaSel.Top);
}

return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
```

After, you need to fill **TRECT** *ListViewMouseOldAreaSel* in **WM_LBUTTONDOWN** and **WM_MOUSEMOVE**. And call *InvalidateRect* for *ListView* in **WM_LBUTTONUP**.

**Note:** I have translated code in *C syntax*, but it may not be entirely correct. Please check before using...